# Facebook App into Page Tab

Tags: facebook-apps

We have created a game which is accessible as an app but cannot get the game into a tab. During the submission stage it reads:

"Our review team will use this page to test your Page Tab app. Your Page Tab app must be installed on this page. Only pages that you admin will appear in the dropdown."

I am admin on 3 different pages, one was built specifically for testing the tab but it says there are no eligible pages and the option is ghosted out, even when a new page is created via this step.

Am i missing something or does anyone else know what i'm doing wrong?